# Connect as client in a remote socket server

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, fsockopen

I need to build a simple PHP service socket to connect as client with a remote socket server and lintening then. The problem is that I need to connect with the host URL and not the host IP.

I've tried with `socket_create()` method, but it only connect using IP. Other method that I've tried was `stream_socket_server()` that allow URL conections, but I cannot keep up a listening to receive responses.

```php
echo "Socket started...\n";

$server = 'ssl://sockserver.com/moreurl/params?56298';
$host = "sockserver.com";
$port = 80;
set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result = socket_connect($socket, $server, $port);
socket_bind($socket, $host);
socket_listen($socket);

while (true) {
  $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024);
  if($result){
    echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
  }
}

socket_close($socket);
```

So, I need to keep a listening to a remote server Socket as PHP client using an URL like host.

Comment: I'm missing `socket_bind` and `socket_listen` in your code... you won't be able to establish a connection without binding your socket to an actual IP address...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz, thank you for your reply, I changed my code here with this methods and I was suprised with the error: "socket_read(): unable to read from socket [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected". Is that structure correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the [ratchetphp/Pawl library at Github](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl). This library allow to connect as client in a WSS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to make yourself familiar with socket programming... for example, your $address is an URL - but a socket doesn't understand URLs. You'd have to use an IP address (for AF_INET) or an Unix socket path (for AF_UNIX).

I'll provide you with 2 scripts, a very basic socket server + socket client... feel free to do whatever you want with it.

The server:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_bind($socket, '0.0.0.0', 9999);
if (socket_listen($socket)) {
    $nsocket = socket_accept($socket);

    $exit = false;
    while(!$exit && $s = socket_read($nsocket, 100)) {
        $s = trim($s);

        if ($s == 'quit') {
            $exit = true;
            $a = 'Bye';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Received "'.$s.'" from '.$nsocket . PHP_EOL;
            $a = 'You wrote "'.$s.'"';
        }

        socket_write($nsocket, $a."\n");
    }
    socket_write($nsocket, "Bye\n");
    socket_close($nsocket); 
}
```

The client:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 9999);
echo '> ';
while( ($data = fgets(STDIN)) && trim($data) != 'quit') {

    if (strlen($data))
        socket_write($socket, $data);
    $answer = '';
    while($ret = socket_read($socket, 1)) { 
        $answer .= $ret;
        if ($ret == "\n") break;
    }
    echo '< '.$answer;
    echo '> ';
}
```

Comment: Thanks once again. My english is no so good, so maybe I cannot to explain my problem very well. My problem is exactly this: I need to create a client using the URL Socket server and not using IP, because I have to pass some params. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "URL Socket Server". Sockets reside on OSI layer 4 (transport), while encryption (ssl), dns or http are on layer 6 (presentation). The protocol stack only works from higher to lower layers. Layer 4 doesn't understand an URL, because that concept is introduced on a higher level. TCP or UDP work with IP addresses (as IP is defined on the network layer 3)

Comment: Right, this make total sense for me... So I'll try to connect only with IP and send the params by header on the Handshake. Thanks your very much for your help!!